# creating setupcontroller in map for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am trying to develop the setupcontroller for map it like setting page where user can choose at what time or at rich the some distance user then see his current location automatically. 
I try this:

```
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

but it work one one time. I give user option at time or what distance he need just set and when he rich at that position. Then app show him the current location ON MAPView NOT on UIlable  Or in table view. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling

```
  [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

in your delegate?

Is your

```
   didFailWithError:
```

method called?

Comment: Thank you for answer I need check it http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801 it show detailes in the table but need it on the map how can i do this

Comment: Here is some map sample code:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746